# Error loading shared library libstdc++.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by)

Tags: java, linux, docker, kubernetes, jprofiler

I am seeing the following error while trying to attach jprofiler to my zulu jvm inside a container.

Error :

```
Error loading shared library libstdc++.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by
```

JVM argument passed:

```
-agentpath:/data/jprofiler11.0.2/bin/linux-x86/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849,nowait
```

Comment: Add more details please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the container image used was not having the required libraries.  I used a different image with libraries and made it work.

Comment: Which image did you use for it?

Comment: Which image did you use for the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

you need add the missing shared library.

RUN this cmd can fix it: `apk add libstdc++6 libstdc++`

Comment: This worked for us. We were using Alpine OS and adding the command to Dockerfile helped.

Answer (score 0):

I know export *.so to LD_LIBRARY_PATH,then the program can find it.

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path1:path2`

but I want know that do not use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, how to find *.so

I try write like `-agentpath:a.so:b.so=opt1=x,opt2=y`,but it is not work